# "bash-4.3$" shows up on the shell when I switch to a specific user, why?

Tags: bash, prompt

It shows this prompt, when I switch to a specific user:

```
bash-4.3$
```

When I switch to a specific user, this shows up. But when I switch to other users it doesn't.

Comment: What is the passwd line for the user with the problem. Please post in your question the result of `grep PS1 /etc/bash.bashrc` and the result of `grep PS1 $HOME/.bashrc` for the user with the problem.

Comment: Also check shell options with  `$-` and `set -o`

Comment: @isaac, Sorry for the trouble. I have solved the issue by adding .bashrc on the home directory of the user (which is because I try to understand what you have answered and what are the words all about - which I have searched most about .bashrc). Thank you so much for the information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual way to reproduce what you report is to do:

```
bash -norc
```

Or

```
bash --posix
```

And the PS1 prompt falls back to the default as no rc files are loaded. The two usual rc files are `/etc/bash.bashrc` and `~/.bashrc`. The first is loaded for all users, the second should exist for each user in each user home directory.

As the PS1 is usually set in `/etc/bash.bashrc`, and some other times in `~/.bashrc`, check that the user with problems has a `~/.bashrc` installed.

Comment: Not necessarily.  `bash --posix` also produces such prompt, even if `~/.bashrc` exists.

Comment: @isaac, Sorry for the trouble. I have solved the issue by adding .bashrc on the home directory of the user (which is because I try to understand what you have answered and what are the words all about - which I have searched most about .bashrc). Thank you so much for the information.